# Do I have to treat the wood before I assemble it?

Tags: furniture

I am planning on making a sofa. I have my tools and my wood. Do I have to apply any type of treatment to the wood before I assemble it? I mean at the end I'm going to be stapling textiles on it and adding pillows and cushions.

Comment: You're fine leaving it completely bare, regardless of the wood species.

Comment: You might want to be sure to sand it to a nice, smooth finish so you're not snagging any stuffing or tearing the fabric as you stretch it across the framing. Even if those snags/tears are on the inside at the bottom - the tear in the fabric will spread over time.

Answer (score 3):

Since a sofa will almost surely be an indoor piece of furniture, completely protected from the weather, you are fine leaving it untreated. Every commercial sofa that I have seen the inside of is constructed of untreated wood.